# Can I measure half wave DC voltages using a multimeter? Will it damage my multimeter? Because it is not pure DC or AC

Tags: dc, multimeter

Can I measure half wave DC voltages using a multimeter? Will it damage my multimeter? Because it is not pure DC. Will the AC measurement show any reading?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Pure DC and pure AC are theoretical impossible situations. Think about it then be realistic.

Answer (score 4):

With a half-wave voltage, your multimeter will give an indication. It's very unlikely to be damaged, as long as you stay within the permitted range of the meter. Bear in mind that if you are applying a half-wave rectified waveform going to 2000 V peak, it will read less than 1000 V, I fried a meter under just such circumstances.

Depending on the type of meter, you can interpret that indication into a measurement. Most cheap meters will read the DC average (not the RMS) on DC, and the average high-passed rectified scaled for RMS assuming a sinewave (not the RMS) on AC.

If it's a true RMS meter, it will have that function on AC, and it might or might not have it as an option on DC measurements.

Comment: "Most cheap meters will read the DC average (not the RMS) on DC" – What's the difference? If I set a multimeter to DC and measure a signal whose instantaneous voltage at time *t* is (3 + 4 sin(120 pi *t* / 1 second)) V, I expect it to show "the DC average" of 3 V, regardless of whether it's a cheap meter or an expensive one. I don't know what "the RMS" could mean in the context of taking a DC measurement.

Comment: The RMS V is higher which addsr the DC average and the   Vac RMS

Answer (score 0):

tl; dr: yes, you can. It’s even a useful thing to do. Just make sure the voltage doesn’t exceed the meter’s rating.

Using DC voltage to measure AC or AC to measure DC will not damage a DMM type meter, so long as its max voltages aren't exceeded. The DMM DC input can accept negative or positive voltage.

Analog meter, slightly different: AC voltage on DC setting could damage the movement, but DC voltage on AC setting won't cause a problem.

How does a meter actually measure DC or AC? It depends.

- DC setting: the signal is averaged (low-pass filtered) to yield a mean value. It will ‘reject’ the AC part if it’s a high enough frequency, otherwise it will show up as variation in the DC. Most meters show the average value; 'true RMS' meters will calculate RMS.
- AC setting: a DC blocking capacitor is inserted. The DC component is blocked. The remaining AC signal is rectified and filtered internally, making an internal DC signal that the meter measures. Inexpensive meters will estimate RMS based on the average; 'true RMS' meters use the RMS calculation.

More about average vs. RMS here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/average-voltage.html

Example: 2V p-p sine wave (1V \$V_{pk}\$), DC biased +1V. What will the meter show?

- DC: measures +1V (average DC value). AC is rejected.
- AC: measures 0.707V (RMS) or 0.637V (average). DC is rejected.

---

A discussion ensued about measuring an off-the-line power supply rectifier output on DC and AC. You can do this with a meter, but be careful - the voltages are lethal.

Let’s assume 120V mains voltage, with no load and no filter on the output, just the raw rectifier output.

What will the AC and DC settings show at the rectifier output? For the sim and calculations below, use \$V_{pk}\$, or \$120 \sqrt(2) V\$ (about **169.71V**).

[Simulation here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEB2B0DMzIBYBMZcEFsEA2MbEBSKqmhAUwFowwAoAExF2xrGVLdkucNkoiwAOV442AJxDoAHJTABOEcvG8o4ePrYBzISNzCT3JUt2Q2AN249wA8KT4u%20IN67XQsZM2wVZGQKGyhoBDYAdxQcZ0EsVQ0oGLjxcyTuHVsFLPURLJ4aPn14eT1IawLK62LdMDK4NMaqi1a6nJa4apcO8BTbLnR4-kEzCTFucGk4bDTcJzHs90FbWLBvZc2aRcp1iwnFFQsDrQTj5JEzk-rzo6GqLZcEFOWJWdljIN3zH8trCV7FQpst-stPFtSL5-KRAsFQvsbJE0sRVC9nmtUW8XG5eljYniLqQyBcDuCXP96uSlLsdFTzDTfoV4g80iTBMt8h40mpMbUyWlkLdzP02bFhdoaJLTkKTlzbl1Yip8SA%20atUg4VRcZRDwF4%20NC-JAAsggtgQmEShEosYZUd7VYbGwAB7cMDoRRqNSKMDWXgibQgABiAFcADbhgA6AGcAOoAQzsDFdVEIXp9pHQlADICDAAkE%20GAGaxxPJ1MqQOQCB85B5%20JByQAe1jACUGABjAAuAEti72GHJOIc2vV3jMZPMuEdcG0RujxpO5gtzHO6mulYcdLPGS1vHtFKynGdRi50HPBbELxqb459mk74eF-fUrEjhQMhJcIDV9-rOcBC-te8o-pcgrNvqpBImACCwcQiiXjA1zTBA6BsJBgjQQ0cFEJQd4wPAwoEEgEAiII6GQfW2F8LhCEEbAcDEempgoIobBAA). Compare this with the theoretical calculations below.

**Full-wave rectifier**

- AC RMS: \$V_{pk} {1 \over \sqrt{2}}\$, or **120V**, less diode drop. [calculation here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28average%20of%20%28120*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%29%5E2%20from%200%20to%202*pi%29)
- DC average: \$V_{pk} {2 \over \pi}\$, or **108V**, less diode drop. [calculation here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%28average%20of%20%28120*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%29%20from%200%20to%20pi%20-%20average%20of%20%28120*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%29%20from%20pi%20to%202*pi%29)

**Half-wave rectifier**

Intuitively, we know that the AC RMS and DC average voltage should be less than for full-wave, but by how much? The RMS calculation is more complicated because the signal is no longer a periodic sine: half the cycle is blocked off.

Average DC? That's simpler, it's half the full-wave value.

- AC RMS: \$V_{pk} {1 \over 2}\$ or **84.85V**, less diode drop. [calculation here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%281%2F2%20%28average%20of%20%28120*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%29%5E2%20from%200%20to%20pi%20%2B%20average%20of%20%280*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%29%5E2%20from%20pi%20to%202*pi%29%29)
- DC average: \$V_{pk} {1 \over \pi}\$ or **54V**, less diode drop. [calculation here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%28average%20of%20%28120*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%29%20from%200%20to%20pi%20-%20average%20of%20%280*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%29%20from%20pi%20to%202*pi%29)

Note: for RMS I initially 'cheated' and did a spreadsheet RMS calculation over the half-wave cycle. Result? Also **84.85V**. This matches the piecewise integral approach above.

Finally, for 240V mains, double all the above values.

Comment: what will it read on DC?

Comment: It depends on the wave shape. If it’s a full-wave rectified sine, probably 0.707 of the peak, if it’s half-wave then 0.707/2. Square wave - duty cycle * peak. Etc.

Comment: that 0.707 sounds remarkably precise, almost RMS-inspired. Have you tried integrating a rectified cosine wave to see what the DC average actually is? At least you say probably!

Comment: @hacktastical - think again about RMS on dc ranges.

Comment: By my calculations, if you take a 120 V RMS sine wave and fully rectify it, the resulting signal has an average of 240 sqrt(2) / pi ≈ 108 V ([Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=average+of+%7C120*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%7C+from+0+to+2+pi)), and an RMS of 120 sqrt(pi^2 - 8) / pi ≈ 52 V ([Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28average+of+%28%7C120*sqrt%282%29*sin%28x%29%7C+-+240+sqrt%282%29+%2F+pi%29%5E2+from+0+to+2+pi%29)).

Comment: Rectified 120V RMS AC is... 120V RMS. Not 52V. Formula messed up?